# Mysql Update not working, with no mysql error

Tags: php, mysql

I am sure there is something simple I am missing, but this update query is not working. It is returning the 'We were unable to reset your password...' error, but there is no mysql_error() shown.

```
    $usr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    $fpquery = "SELECT id, usr, email, rand FROM membertable WHERE usr = '$usr' AND email = '$email'";

    $fpresult = mysql_query($fpquery,$link);

    if(mysql_num_rows($fpresult) < 1) {


        $_SESSION['msg']['forgotpassword-err']= 'This username or email does not exist in our records. Make sure your capitalization is correct and please try again.';

        echo header("Location: ../forgotpassword.php");

    }

elseif(mysql_num_rows($fpresult) == 1) {

    $rand = $fpresult['rand'];

    $pass = substr(md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].microtime().rand(1,100000)),0,6);
    $insertpassword = hash("sha256",$pass.$rand);
    $fpid = $fpresult['id'];
    $fpusr = $fpresult['usr'];
    $fpemail = $fpresult['email'];

    $updatequery = "UPDATE membertable SET
                pass='$insertpassword',
                yn='2'
                WHERE id='$fpid' AND usr='$fpusr' AND email='$fpemail'";
    $updateresult = mysql_query($updatequery, $link);

    if(mysql_affected_rows($updateresult) == 1)
    {

        $_SESSION['msg']['forgotpassword-err']='You will receive an email with your temporary password. Please return to the home page and log in with this password to reset your password permanently';

        echo header("Location: ../forgotpassword.php");

    }

    else {

        $_SESSION['msg']['forgotpassword-err']='We were unable to reset your password. Please contact customer service at 888-888-8888 and mention the following error: ' . mysql_error();

        echo header("Location: ../forgotpassword.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you define `$fpid`?

Comment: dump the query and run it through mysql console ..... So that you will get a clear idea about whats wrong?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @AwladLiton whoops i had taken that out, in my frustration to see if maybe it just wasn't matching the ID. It is edited to include $fpid. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you fetch the results of $fpquery at some time with mysql_fetch_array() ?

Answer (score 0):

First always use limit 1 if you need one row.

```
$fpquery = "SELECT id, usr, email, rand FROM membertable WHERE usr = '$usr' AND email = '$email' LIMIT 1";
```

You need to fetch the result:
try this:

```
$result = mysql_query($fpquery,$link);
$fpresult = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: I tried fetching the array. It still didn't work. And there is still no mysql_error.

Answer (score 0):

The update could be affecting either zero rows or more than one row - neither of these scenarios would produce an error, but would result in the 'We were unable to reset your password.' message.

Comment: Right, but it is making it past the first section where it finds the user. So if it is finding the user, why isn't it updating the user? I also added LIMIT 1 to the query so it cannot be updating more than 1. It should only be zero or 1.